# Oracle Update using Lag function

Tags: sql, oracle, lag

I am trying to use a `lag` function to `update` effective start dates in a `SCD2` dimension.  I am trying to use a subquery to self join the table based on the PK.  The update will not update based on the previous end date and instead will only update to the default value (which is itself).  When I remove the default value I get an error because the effective start date cannot be null.  When I just use the `select` I get the desired result.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, I'm sure its something simple!

```
update schema.d_account ac1
set effective_start_dt = (select lag(effective_end_dt, 1, effective_start_dt) over(partition by id order by effective_end_dt asc) 
                          from schema.d_account ac2
                          where ac1.account_dim_key = ac2.account_dim_key),
audit_last_update_dt = sysdate,
where id in '0013600000USKLqAAP'
```

Table:

[image]

Desired results:

[image]

Comment: can you let us know the error you get? i don't see a problem with the query here.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be one of these reasons why your update is not working. I do not know the exact structure of your table. You have not provided the sample data. If your account_dim_key is a unique for each row then the `select lag() ... from schema.d_account ac2 where ac1.account_dim_key = ac2.account_dim_key)` will return one row and you will effectively update `effective_start_dt` to `effective_start_dt` (being the default value of the lag function)

If your account_dim_key is the same for all these rows you have provided as a sample then the `select lag() ... from schema.d_account ac2 where ac1.account_dim_key = ac2.account_dim_key)` will return multiple rows and Oracle will complain that the UPDATE is not possible (there is a specific error message, I do not remember the exact wording.

To make your query work you need to use a different approach:

```
update schema.d_account ac1
set effective_start_dt = (select prev_dt from
                          (select lag(effective_end_dt, 1, effective_start_dt) over(partition by id order by effective_end_dt asc) as prev_dt
                          , ROWID as rid
                          from schema.d_account ac2) a where a.rid = ROWID),
audit_last_update_dt = sysdate,
where id in '0013600000USKLqAAP'
```

So, basically you have a sub-query `a` with the ROWID column where you build the previous date. For the UPDATE statement you join this sub-query by the ROWID.

Note: if your account_dim_key is unique for each row you can use it in place of the ROWID: you may get better performance depending on the indexes you have for your table

UPDATE: the above query may give you a bad performance. You will be better off with the MERGE statement below:

```
MERGE INTO (SELECT id, effective_start_dt, ROWID rid, audit_last_update_dt 
   FROM schema.d_account WHERE id in '0013600000USKLqAAP') ac1
USING (select lag(effective_end_dt, 1, effective_start_dt) over(partition by id order by effective_end_dt asc) as prev_dt
      , ROWID as rid
      from schema.d_account) ac2
ON (ac1.rid = ac2.rid) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ac1.effective_start_dt = ac2.prev_dt,
ac1.audit_last_update_dt = sysdate;
```

Comment: I initally replaced ROWID wtih acocunt_dim_key since this is the PK on the table, but this impacted performance (taking over 1 hour to update 100K records) but when I run the above query using ROWID I get an error that subquery returns more than 1 row.  How can I use ROWID?

Comment: update using ROWID update dexwhs.d_account_veeva ac1
set effective_start_dt = (select prev_dt from
                          (select lag(effective_end_dt, 1, effective_start_dt) over(partition by id order by effective_start_dt, account_dim_key) as prev_dt
                          , ROWID as rid
                          from dexwhs.d_account_veeva ac2) a where a.rid = ROWID ),
                          audit_last_update_dt = sysdate

Comment: update using account_dim_key : update dexwhs.d_account_veeva ac1
set effective_start_dt = (select prev_dt from
                          (select lag(effective_end_dt, 1, effective_start_dt) over(partition by id order by effective_end_dt asc) as prev_dt
                          , account_dim_key as rid
                          from dexwhs.d_account_veeva ac2) a where a.rid = account_dim_key),
audit_last_update_dt = sysdate

Comment: I have added a different statement with the `MERGE`

Comment: Thank you for the alternative.  However I am getting an error-- cannot update effective start date to null (this field cannot be null) with the modified merge statement.  But when I run the select it gives me my expected results for each record/account dim key (effective end date from previous row)

Comment: I fixed it by moving the WHERE clause to the ac1